# Can't stop CountDownTimer

Tags: android, countdowntimer

Good day! I try to make countdown timer till date, but I have next problem: when I set date and time - it's work's fine, but when I try to reset timer and then reload application I still saw the previous timer countdown. I have already try everything that I can even imaging.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {


TextView tv_days;
TextView tv_hours;
TextView tv_minutes;
TextView tv_seconds;
TextView tv_msg;
ImageButton btnTimer;
ImageButton btnExit;

long total_millisec;
CountDownTimer cdt;
TimerPreference timerPreference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv_days = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.days);
    tv_hours = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hours);
    tv_minutes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minutes);
    tv_seconds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seconds);
    tv_msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);
    btnTimer = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.setTimer);
    btnExit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.resetTimer);

    final Intent setTimer = new Intent(this, ShowActivity.class);

    timerPreference = new TimerPreference(this);
    total_millisec = timerPreference.getTime();

    if(total_millisec != 0){
        setTime();
    }



    View.OnClickListener mainWin = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.setTimer:
                    startActivity(setTimer);
                    break;
                case R.id.resetTimer:
                    resetTimer();
                    break;
            }

        }
    };
    btnTimer.setOnClickListener(mainWin);
    btnExit.setOnClickListener(mainWin);

}


public void setTime() {

    cdt = new CountDownTimer(total_millisec, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            timerPreference.setTime(millisUntilFinished);

            long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millisUntilFinished);
            millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(days);
            long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished);
            millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours);
            long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished);
            millisUntilFinished -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes);
            long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished);



            setScreenData(String.valueOf(days),
                    String.valueOf(hours),
                    String.valueOf(minutes),
                    String.valueOf(seconds));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.e("TIMER:"," FINISH!");
        }
    };
    cdt.start();
}

public void setScreenData(String setD, String setH,String setM, String setS){
    tv_days.setText(setD);
    tv_hours.setText(setH);
    tv_minutes.setText(setM);
    tv_seconds.setText(setS);
    tv_msg.setText("");

}

private void resetTimer(){

    AlertDialog.Builder quitDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    quitDialog.setTitle("Reset Timer?");

    quitDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });

    quitDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            cancelTimer();
            recreate();
        }
    });

    quitDialog.show();
}

void cancelTimer() {
    if(cdt!=null) {
        cdt.cancel();
    }
    timerPreference.clearPreferences();

}

}
```

I logged this code for some hours, and I have noticed that even after I cancel timer, clear preferences and reload app, "total_millisec = timerPreference.getTime();" in onCreate still have time information...
Thank you in advance, for any answer.

**UDP:**

**TimerPreference.java**

```
class TimerPreference {

private SharedPreferences prefs;

TimerPreference(Context context){
    prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Timer",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

void setTime(Long time){
    prefs.edit().putLong("time", time).apply();
}

Long getTime(){
    return prefs.getLong("time", 0);
}

void clearPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.apply();
}
```

}

**UPD2:**
I logged code using String.valueOf(timerPreference.getTime()) and get that when I press reset I get "TIME-IN-cancelTimer: 0", than activity reloaded by onrecreate(); and I get "TIME-IN-onCreate: 0", but when I close app and open again - I get "TIME-IN-onCreate: 47025952", so now I almoust sure that the problem is in class TimerPreference...but I still can't find solution.

After hours I have noticed another pattern: if to set time, reset the timer and restart the application - everything works as it should. But if to set the time, restart it, and then reset the timer - after next app start, it again start countdown.

Comment: Can you post `recreate();` method ?

Comment: What is `TimerPreference` class here ?

Comment: @SanjayKakadiya "recreate()" is the standart android method that reload activity

Answer (score 0):

Add `timerPreference.setTime(0);` after `timerPreference.clearPreferences();` in `cancelTimer()` method.

Comment: I have already try this "timerPreference.setTime(0L);", but it won't help.

Comment: unfortunately it's still the same problem. I logged code using String.valueOf(timerPreference.getTime()) and get that when I press reset I get "TIME-IN-cancelTimer: 0", that activity reloaded by onrecreate(); and I get "TIME-IN-onCreate: 0", but then when I close app and open again - I get "TIME-IN-onCreate: 47025952"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `editor.commit();` in `clearPreferences()` method of `TimerPreference` class

Comment: Nope...still the same result

Comment: Mmm, use commit() also in setTime() method.

Comment: Nope( A noticed that preferences clears, only when I kill app